# Show that $\theta(x)=x^2$ from $\mathbb{R}^*$, the nonzero real number under multiplication, is a homomorphism.

Tags: group-homomorphism

Show that $\theta(x)=x^2$ from $\mathbb{R}^*$, the nonzero real number under multiplication, is a group homomorphism.

How to deal with this one?

Comment: Check the definition.

Comment: A function from A to B, with binary operations "*", is a homorphism if f(x*y)= f(x)*f(y).  A homomorphism is not necessarily "one-to-one"  or "onto.  With f(x)= x^2, what is f(x*y)?  What are f(x) and f(y)?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: You must show that following for $\mathbb{R^*}=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$:

- $\theta(1_{\mathbb{R^*}})=1_{\mathbb{R^*}}$
- $\theta(ab)=\theta{(a)}\theta{(b)}$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R^*}$

First one is obvious.

Second one just use commutativity of $\mathbb{R^*}$.

$\theta(ab)=(ab)^2=(ab)(ab)=a(ba)b=a(ab)b=(aa)(bb)=a^2b^2=\theta{(a)}\theta{(b)}$

Comment: What would be the end result?

Comment: I wrote  one hint again.